# Seleccionar fechas dentro de un rango dado, utilizando searchsorted

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Dispongo de un DataFrame con fechas como índices.

```
#Consulta Stackoverflow
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = "2016-01-04"
end = "2019-01-04"

GOOG = web.DataReader("GOOG", "yahoo", start, end)
df = GOOG[["Close"]][start:end].copy(deep=True)
```

Dentro de este rango de fechas, necesito seleccionar `x` fechas, uniformemente distanciadas.
El script que intento desarrollar es:

**OPCION 1**

```
# Lista de fechas, empezando con 'start', y finalizando con 'end', distanciadas int(df.shape[0] /12 días 
lista_fechas = pd.date_range(start = "2016-01-04",  end = "2020-01-04", freq ='63D')          

# Elimina fechas fuera del rango de análisis
lista_fechas_filtradas = lista_fechas[lista_fechas < df.index[-1]]

# Fechas en las que se realiza la aportación
fechas_aportación = df.index.searchsorted(lista_fechas_filtradas)
```

Me devuelve:

```
[  0  43  87 130 174 219 261 304 348 391 435 479 521 564 608 652 696 739]
```

El resultado debería ser similar/aproximado al que obtengo con este otro script:

**OPCION 2**

```
"""Divide el rango de fechas del índice del DataFrame, en 12 partes"""
nºfilas = df.shape[0] 
paso = int(nºfilas /12)
indices = np.arange(0, nºfilas, paso).astype(int)
print (f"Indices {indices}")
```

que me devuelve `Indices [  0  63 126 189 252 315 378 441 504 567 630 693 756]`

No coinciden en ni en los números de fila, ni en el número de elementos, que deberían ser 12.

Cual puede ser la causa de este error?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las fechas con que trabajas cubren un rango de 1096 días, como se puede comprobar:

```py
import datetime

start = "2016-01-04"
end = "2019-01-04"
s = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d")
e = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%d")
print(e-s)
```

```
1096 days, 0:00:00
```

Ya que mediante `date_range()` estás pidiendo que genere fechas en ese rango separadas entre sí 51 días (que es lo que dice el parámetro `"51D"`, el número de fechas a generar será de:

```
>>> 1096/51
21.49019607843137
```

21 fechas, más la fecha inicial. En total 22 que es justamente la longitud de la lista que muestras en primer lugar. Y que no es 12 ni veo por qué tendría que serlo.

Por otro lado, la segunda estrategia básicamente toma el número de filas de `df` para intentar extraer de él 12 fechas, por el método de crear un "paso" igual a la longitud del dataframe entre 12. No sabemos cuántas filas tiene tu `df` exactamente, pero pongamos por caso que tiene 758 filas por ejemplo. En ese caso al dividir por 12 no sale exacto, sino que sale 758/12 = 63.16666666

Ya que lo truncas a entero, te quedas con 63, y luego eliges índices de 63 en 63. Debido a la truncación has hecho un redondeo hacia abajo, por lo que obtendrás más de 12 valores al muestrear de este modo.

Por otro lado no se garantizaría de todas formas que las fechas salgan equidistantes, ya que eso depende de que `df` tenga realmente una fecha diferente (y equidistante) en cada una de sus filas. Si por el contrario contiene fechas repetidas o hay rangos de fechas que no aparecen en `df`, el método de ir tomando las fechas "equiespaciando" los índices no te va a producir necesariamente fechas equiespaciadas.

Answer (score 0):

Con la **OPCION1** buscaba conseguir 12 fechas, mas o menos equidistantes entre sí, dentro del rango de fechas df.index.
`df` tiene `df.shape[0]`, 757 filas. En estas 757 filas quiero hacer 13 sub-rangos de aproximadamente 757/12 ~ 63 días. Un error que ya corregí en el código, es que use `freq=51D` en lugar de `freq=63D`. Con esta frecuencia,  el resultado son 17 sub-rangos.

- `lista_fechas` es una lista con todas las fechas posibles entre `start` y `end`.
- `lista_fechas_filtradas` elimina de `lista_fechas` todas las fechas que no se encuentran en `df.index`.
- `fechas_aportación` selecciona de `df_index` las fechas más próximas a las seleccionadas en `lista_fechas_filtradas`.

Si `periods = 12` y `frec = "63D"`, mismos parámetros utilizados en la **OPCION2**, ¿no deberian dar un resultado parecido,al menos en cuanto al número de sub-grupos?